# ViewModels, Data Models and Models in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Having 3 copies of the same model, how does this fit in with DRY principle? Or is DRY sacrificed to bring in better testability?

IS there a method that people use to automatically update each model? eg. If i have a User model/viewmodel/datamodel, and want to add IsDeleted property, I have to change in 3 places.

Am I missing something here??

Comment: take a look [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109547/orm-entities-vs-domain-entities-under-entity-framework-6-0)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question, you may be able to solve most of your issues with custom validator classes and inheritance.

[How do I remain DRY with asp.net mvc view models & data annotation attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377578/how-do-i-remain-dry-with-asp-net-mvc-view-models-data-annotation-attributes)